# Create thumbs for a lot of MP4 videos with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have a folder with 1000 MP4 videos and I would like to generate thumbnails for the videos.

Currently the videos are named like this:

```
test.mp4 test1.mp4 test2.mp4 test3.mp4
```

I would like the thumbnails images to be named like this:

```
test-thumb.jpg test1-thumb.jpg test2-thumb.jpg test3-thumb.jpg
```

Would you please help me with the right command to achieve that? I'm using CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in '' `seq 1 1000`;do
    ffmpeg -i test${i}.mp4 -vf  "thumbnail" -frames:v 1 test${i}-thumb.jpg
done
```

Comment: Better: `for i in {1..1000}` – Bash has range expansion: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace

Comment: I'm always using ksh.

Comment: Why use a sequence? `for f *.mp4;do ffmpeg -i $f -vf  "thumbnail" -frames:v 1 $(basename $f .mp4)-thumb.jpg; done`

Comment: In a deleted answer (since he cannot comment), the OP is asking how to capture thumbnails from a few seconds in (e.g. 10) or from the middle of the video. Perhaps you could amend your answer.

Comment: No need to amend. Look, I used a video filter called **thumbnail**. It tries to choose the most representative frame from the first 100.
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#thumbnail

Comment: We'd like answers to be more than just a few lines of code. If you could add a little more explanation on how to use the filter or how else to get thumbnails from a different part of the movie, that'd be better.