# Can you batch generate thumbnails with tumbler?

Tags: command-line, thumbnails, xfce4

I was wondering if there is any way to generate thumbnails from all files (image and video media) in a folder with (preferably) the command line or anything else really. I use xfce4 and tumbler. Please do not give systemd-specific answers, as I do not use this service.

Comment: I'd use FFmpeg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145238/create-thumbnail-from-video-using-ffmpeg & https://superuser.com/a/608125/1482432

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Gantendo Is there a way to do that with jpeg and the like too? Also, do I just put those in my ~/.cache/thumbnails folder or is there somewhere else?

Comment: @Community I'm not sure how much more specific I can get. Can you give an example?

Comment: Community is a bot, it is not able to answer you. https://superuser.com/questions/1263538/create-thumbs-for-a-lot-of-mp4-videos-with-ffmpeg & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265607/how-should-i-batch-make-thumbnails-with-the-original-images-located-in-multiple

Comment: With imagemagick you can make it even cooler. https://superuser.com/questions/1739297/ffmpeg-and-creating-a-single-image-made-up-of-a-grid-of-thumbnails-from-a-video